# I'm not able to solve any of these puzzles. How can I get started?

Tags: solvability

I'd really like to solve a puzzle but I can never see any pattern or anything. Is there something that can teach me? I've also read about being familiar with puzzle types but I don't even know how to get started with that.
I would appreciate some comments, thank you!

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=puzzle

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Without being more specific, this question is almost certainly "too broad", and likely to be closed. Can you be more specific about what *type* of puzzle you're asking about, and if possible, where you get tripped up?

Comment: For example, the ones about lateral thinking where not much information is given and you have to think of a solution in a creative way, or those about matchsticks I quite like but don't really understand.